# Для чего в MySQL может использоваться конструкция tbl_name.column_name?

Tags: mysql

Для чего в MySQL может использоваться конструкция `tbl_name.column_name`? Просьба привести примеры использования или иначе объяснить, в каких ситуациях обозначенное выражение может быть полезно.

Comment: В смысле как? Ваш вопрос не ясен.

Comment: Собственно как угодно и в любом месте где может стоять имя колонки

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, примеры команд, где используется.

Comment: @Mike, а какой в этом смысл?

Comment: @jisecayeyo Используется во всех "командах" языка SQL. Вам справочник по языку SQL сюда переписать ?

Comment: @jisecayeyo Смысл - если в одном запросе используются одноименные колонки нескольких таблиц что бы было ясно колонка из какой таблицы в данном месте имеется ввиду

Answer (score 3, accepted):

например так

```
SELECT tbl1_name.column_name1, tbl2_name.column_name1
FROM tbl1_name, tbl2_name
WHERE
tbl1_name.column_name2=tbl2_name.column_name2
```